# Ubuntu 20.04 AMD Raid Driver

Tags: 20.04, initramfs, amd-ryzen

I have a problems to install ubuntu 20.04 on my PC, I'm using AMD's raid and i was found a driver [Driver](https://github.com/thopiekar/rcraid-dkms), i was install that driver and system recognize my disks, but after i install system it can't load. How i can add rcraid module to initramfs?

My system is: AMD Ryzen 3700x with B450 chiptet.